# How to find an element with Xpath with an attribute and w/o another attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium, webdriver

This is my Xpath query:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"continue-button\" and not(contains(@class=\"disabled-button\"))]"));
```

I am having trouble locating the element with the id of continue-button and not the class of disabled-button. I am obviously writing the query wrong, but I am not sure of the issue.  I am unfamiliar with the Xpath syntax to use in this situation.

Comment: Give the relevant html part too.. to help you out,.

Comment: Point of order: if you are finding multiple elements with the same ID, [your HTML is invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/struct/global.html#h-7.1.4.1).

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot that I can't have duplicate IDs to begin with.

Comment: Aside from that, the xpath you're using looks okay syntax-wise, but is hard to troubleshoot without seeing the page it's run against.

Comment: I think your xpath should look like 
`"//*[@id='continue-button' and not(contains(@class, 'disabled-button'))]"`

Comment: Indeed, `contains()` expects 2 arguments, not `something=value`, but `something, value`

Comment: @user2121620 did the tips help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xpath:

```
//*[@id=\"continue-button\" and not(contains(@class=\"disabled-button\"))]
```

Should be:

```
//*[@id="continue-button"][not(contains(@class, "disabled-button"))]
```

I highly suggest if you use Firebug to install something like [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) to test out your xpath expressions before running them in tests.

Edit: For anybody who may see this in the future, tools like Firebug are no longer necessary. Newer versions of browsers now allow you to enter XPath and CSS expressions in their respective DOM-viewer. For example in Chrome, the hotkey F12 will open the debug tool, and the hotkey Ctrl+F while on the "Elements" tab will open a search bar which you may enter selector expressions into.